# System.IndexOutOfRangeException in standart int variable

Tags: c#, variables, integer

I creating one program, but on function of creating entry I have problem!
Code:

```
string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
if (cmd.Contains("varStr"))
            {
                string name = cmd.Remove(0, 7); // No problems!
                variables.addrStr[variables.addrStrC] = name; // No problems!
                variables.addrStrC++; // There is problem!!!
                Console.WriteLine("OK!"); // This is needs for indicating state
            }
```

Class "variables":

```
class variables
    {
        public static string[] addrStr = { };
        public static string[] valueStr = { };
        public static string[] addrInt = { };
        public static int[] valueInt = { };
        public static int addrStrC, addrIntC;
    }
```

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException occurs when you are trying to access a variable from an array or list that is not there. For example: `int[] number = { 0, 1, 2 }; int number2 = number[7];` There is no 7th variable in `number`. That might not help, but this is the most likely reason why you are being thrown the error. [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is on this line:

```
variables.addrStr[variables.addrStrC] = name;
```

Because the array is initially empty, as in this line: `public static string[] addrStr = { };` and then you try to assign something to the first element of an empty array (that has 0 element), and so it throws the exception.

Comment: Thank you! This is help me!